# Repositorio local Git con demasiados cambios activos en Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, git

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano por esta gran comunidad. Mi problema es , como indica mi título, que cuando trabajo en un repositorio local de Git y lo abro en Visual Studio Code, me salta el siguiente aviso:
[image: El repositorio Git contiene muchos cambios activos, solamente un subconjunto de las características de Git serán habilitadas.pg[1]]

La única solución que he encontrado es borrar todos los cambios del repositorio,si alguien sabe alguna otra, le estaré muy agradecido. 
Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! el git.ignore esta correcto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que significa ese aviso es que en tu carpeta de trabajo tienes muchos (muchísimos) ficheros que, o bien no están bajo control de versiones, o bien han sido modificados pero no han sido "commiteados".

Cualquiera de las dos situaciones son anómalas y deberías evitarlas. Si haces cambios que deseas guardar bajo `git`, añádelos al repositorio. Si por el contrario se trata de ficheros que no quieres guardar en `git`, puedes borrarlos. Si se trata de ficheros que vuelven a aparecer sin que tú puedas hacer nada por evitarlo (por ejemplo, son resultados de compilaciones, etc.) o bien se trata de ficheros que no quieres mantener en `git` pero tampoco quieres borrar porque tu proyecto los necesita (por ejemplo, una carpeta `node_modules`, o similar, con bibliotecas de terceros), debes usar `.gitignore` para decirle a `git` que los ignore, es decir, que no les preste atención.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, totalmente útil! Un saludo

Comment: A mi no me ignora el node modules, sabran por que?

Comment: @Ariel mira aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/525876/7123 seguramente es por eso.