# El gitignore no funciona

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Estoy empezando a subir a GitHub algunos de los mini proyectos que hice para mostrar mi código, quiero hacer uso del archivo .gitignore para que ignore la carpeta img (contiene una imagen) pero, por alguna razón no me funciona.
Si alguien pudiera darme una mano se lo agradecería.

```
img/*
img
```

Este sería el contenido del gitignore pero cuando entro a GitHub la carpeta img aparece y su contenido también.

Comment: Lo más probable es que la carpeta img ya está en tu repositorio, es decir estuvo antes del .gitignore, y por lo tanto los cambios no lo afectan. ¿Puedes compartir la URL de tu repositorio? Así podría indicarte mejor los pasos a seguir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Porque ocurre esto?**

Al hacer un commit `GIT` automaticamente empieza a hacer un `track` de el/los archivos/carpetas dentro de ese commit por lo que tienes que hacer que los deje de `trackear` de manera manual para que el archivo `.gitignore` tenga el comportamiento esperado sobre el repositorio.

**Como evitarlo?**

Para evitar este comportamiento, antes de crear las carpetas/archivos a ignorar primero se deben agregar dichos archivos/carpetas dentro de el archivo `.gitignore` y realizar un `commit` para posteriormente agregar o crear los archivos que no deseas que se `trackeen`

**Primera forma (Recomendada):**

Haciendo un `cd` hacia tu proyecto y ejecutando en la terminal el siguiente comando:

```
git rm --cached <archivo/carpeta>
```

en tu caso seria algo como:

```
git rm --cached img
```

*(suponiendo que la carpeta se llama img y esta en la raiz de tu proyecto)*

**Segunda forma (tratar de evitar):**

Elimina la carpeta o archivos que quieres dejar de `trackear`. A continuación haz un nuevo `commit`. Al crear de nuevo la carpeta/archivo ya no debería ser `trackeado` (teniendolo previamente en el `.gitignore`)

Trata de evitar esta forma ya que creas un `commit` basura en tu historial y puedes solucionarlo de manera más rápida de la primera forma, aun asi pongo esta segunda forma porque es lo primero que nos viene a la mente a muchos al toparnos con estos problemas cuando iniciamos con `git`.

Comment: @nicolás-abelando Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad y resolvió tu problema por favor marcala como RESPUESTA CORRECTA.

Answer (score 3):

El `.gitignore`funciona para archivos que no han sido agregados. Una vez que los agregaste, el archivo no tiene ningún efecto. Podrías eliminarlo de la historia como indica Erik yendo hacia adelante, pero los archivos quedan en la historia de las revisiones anteriores. Si lo quieres eliminar desde un principio, tienes que regresar con un rebase a la revision donde fueron agregados y eliminarlos. Digamos que la revisión donde los archivos fueron agregados es la X:

```
git rebase -i X~ # utilizar el rabo'e cochino
# en la primera linea, va a estar la revisión en cuestión
# cambia el 'pick' de esa línea por un edit o una e
# guarda y cierra
# rebase va a arrancar a ajecutar y se va a colocar justo en esa revisión
# en este punto podrias entonces hacer lo de eliminar los archivos del index
git rm --cached img
# eso lo va a eliminar del index, pero no los toca en tu árbol de trabajo
# en este punto sería ideal modificar el .gitignore para que ignore el directorio:
echo img >> .gitignore # agregar el item al archivo, lo crea si no existe
git add .gitignore
# enmendamos la revisión:
git commit --amend
# en este punto si haces un git status, git no deberia mostrar nada del directorio img
# y al listar lo que hay en la revision, no deberia salir nada para el directorio:
# git ls-tree -r HEAD img
# ese comando no devuelve nada en la salida asi que todo esta bien
# dejamos seguir el rebase
git rebase --continue
```

Y ya nuestra historia está *arreglada*. **ojo** esto reescribe la historia de la rama. Este tipo de acciones hay que evitarlas en repositorios/ramas compartidos.